# how to convert row in to column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

how to convert this table in mysql

```
month | Number_oF_User 
 1    |       3 
 2    |       13 
 3    |       2 
 12   |       3
```

convert in to

```
month             1    2     3        12
number_of_user    3    13    2         3
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: do the pivot of existing data using case statement and dynamic query

Comment: are you using any procedure for it or you want single statement query

Answer (score 1):

You Have to Use Your Query Something Like this:

Select  *
From
(
    Select 'number_of_user' as Itm, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12] 
    From
    (
        Select Month(Your Column) as Mon, Your Number_of_User Column
            From Your Table Name T1
 --where Your Conditions

```
) as SourceTable
Pivot
(
    Your Number_of_User Column
    For Mon in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) as Your TableName t1
```

) A
-- This Will Be Applied If You Want sum of Each Row Horizontally
Cross Apply (Select SUM(Camount) as SumVal, AVG(Camount) as AvgVal From paymentreciept i Where i.PaymentType = a.Itm) b